# Does differentiation of $f(x)=\log(x)$ yield two different results?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

The two different results are :$\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{-1}{x}$.

I read in my book that:

$$\frac{d(\log x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$ where $x>0$

And:

$$\frac{d(\log(-x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$ where $x<0$.

So can't I express a positive number like $3$ as $-(-3)$ and get $2$ answers for derivative of $\log(x)$?

P.S-all logarithms  have base '$e$'.

Comment: Last I checked, $-(-3) = -x$ doesn't have $x < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

no. a) You are talking about the log of 3, not the derivative, and b) the two pieces apply to different value ranges anyway: -(-3) is still 3, and not -3.

Comment: I meant get 2 ans4 for derivative of log(3)

Comment: @Raksh23 The "$x$" inside the $\dfrac{\mathrm d\log(x)}{\mathrm dx}$ is not the same as the "$x$" inside the $\frac1x$. It's just a convenient abuse of notation and you can't really replace the first $x$ with a value.

Comment: @Farnight I understood your 2nd point that I can't replace $x$ by any constant and I have made an edit in question too,but I didn't understand why the derivative won't yield two different answers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of confusion in your question.

First note that a function of a real variable $t$: $f(t)=\log(t)$ is real valued only if $t>0$, because it is (by definition) the inverse function of $y=e^t$ that has only positive values.

Second note that a function is well defined only when it is specified its domain, and functions with different domains are different functions. So:
$$
f:(0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R} \qquad f(x)=\log x
$$ 
is a well defined function that is different from:

$$
g:(-\infty,0) \to \mathbb{R} \qquad g(x)=\log (-x)
$$

The derivatives of the first function is:
$$
f':(0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R} \qquad f'(x)=\frac{1}{x} 
$$
we can find the derivative of the second function using the chain rule and we find:
$$
g':(-\infty,0) \to \mathbb{R} \qquad g'(x)=\frac{1}{-x}\cdot (-1)=g'(x)=\frac{1}{x} 
$$
and this is a different function because it has a different domain, also if the ''form'' is the same.

Note that $f(x)$ is a monotonic increasing function, and $g(x)$ is monotonic decreasing, as we can see from the derivatives.

So, in your question, there is some confusion wan you say that we have two results $\frac{1}{x}$ and $-\frac{1}{x}$, and, it seems that also your idea that we can find two different derivatives for $\log(-(-3))$ come from this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting the second answer from.

Let's start with the standard answer:

$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

and try to derive the result for the second form using the chain rule. We assume $x<0$ and define $y(x)=-x$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\log(-x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\log(y(x))\\
&= \frac{d}{dy}\log(y).y'(x)\\
&= \frac{1}{y}.-1\\
&= \frac{1}{-x}.-1\\
&= \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}
where we have have used the chain rule
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x)) = \frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}
\end{align*}